# npm install -g generator-angular gives error (requires a peer of)

Tags: node.js

Learning Node and trying to install `generator-angular`

running `npm install -g generator-angular`

> WARN EPEERINVALID generator-angular@0.14.0 requires a peer of
>   generator-karma@>=0.9.0 but none was installed.

What does it means and how can I install it?

Answer (score 7):

You should try to `install` all the components in the same time.

```
npm install -g grunt-cli bower yo generator-karma generator-angular
```

worked for me.

Comment: it works like magic! i have tried to install them separately, it won't work

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution was install all in one line

```
npm install -g yo generator-karma generator-angular
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm@3` no longer install peerDependencies automatically. This warning is shown as a result of this change.

If you are not running the tests you do not have to install `karma`.
If you are, `npm install karma>=0.9.0` manually.

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#peerdependencies

Comment: it's giving me 'npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported'

Comment: Well, you can ignore WARN message for the moment and see if it works at all. If it does not work, uninstall and do a clean install, capture log and report to [yeoman/generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues)