# Trouble during generator-angular installation with npm

Tags: angularjs, npm

I ran those commands

```
AT07684S@ZE0PW0NM /d/AAA_Dev2015
$ npm install -g generator-karma --save
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.4.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0.
C:\Users\AT07684S\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── generator-karma@1.0.1

AT07684S@ZE0PW0NM /d/AAA_Dev2015
$ npm install -g generator-angular --save
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.4.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.4.1: the module is now available as 'css-select'
npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.1.0: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0.
C:\Users\AT07684S\AppData\Roaming\npm
├── generator-angular@0.14.0
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY generator-karma@>=0.9.0

npm WARN EPEERINVALID generator-angular@0.14.0 requires a peer of generator-karma@>=0.9.0 but none was install
ed.
```

As you can see I first installed generator-karma 1.0.1 but then when I install generator-angular it fails, supposedly because generator-karma>=0.9.0 is not installed.

What could I do?

Thanks

Comment: there is an issue discussion about this : 
https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/1192

Answer (score 0):

Similar question has already been answered here [npm install -g generator-angular gives error (requires a peer of)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867574/npm-install-g-generator-angular-gives-error-requires-a-peer-of/34488730) and here [UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY generator-karma@>=0.9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419179/unmet-peer-dependency-generator-karma-0-9-0). Wise people suggest to install everything in one line, so try this:

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli bower yo generator-karma generator-angular
```

Works for me, it should help You as well.