# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY generator-karma@>=0.9.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, yeoman-generator-angular

I am installing version 5.6 of `node.js` on a CentOS 7 server with `generator-angular`, and am encountering the following error, in addition to some deprecation warnings:

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY generator-karma@>=0.9.0
```

I am following [instructions from this tutorial](http://start.jcolemorrison.com/how-i-setup-angular-node-projects/).  **How can I resolve this error so that `npm` is able to successfully install `generator-angular`?**  Also, are all the deprecation warnings anything to be concerned about?  Is there a way to install `generator-angular` without using deprecated methods?

Here is the terminal output showing the ERROR along with the deprecation warnings:

```
[root@localhost ~]# npm install -g generator-angular
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.4.1: the module is now available as 'css-select'
npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.1.0: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
/usr/lib
├─┬ generator-angular@0.15.1 
│ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1 
│ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0 
│ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4 
│ │ ├── has-ansi@2.0.0 
│ │ ├── strip-ansi@3.0.0 
│ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0 
│ ├─┬ wiredep@2.2.2 
│ │ ├─┬ bower-config@0.5.2 
│ │ │ ├── graceful-fs@2.0.3 
│ │ │ ├── mout@0.9.1 
│ │ │ ├─┬ optimist@0.6.1 
│ │ │ │ ├── minimist@0.0.10 
│ │ │ │ └── wordwrap@0.0.3 
│ │ │ └── osenv@0.0.3 
│ │ ├─┬ chalk@0.5.1 
│ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@1.1.0 
│ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@0.1.0 
│ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@0.2.1 
│ │ │ ├── strip-ansi@0.3.0 
│ │ │ └── supports-color@0.2.0 
│ │ ├─┬ glob@4.5.3 
│ │ │ ├─┬ inflight@1.0.4 
│ │ │ │ └── wrappy@1.0.1 
│ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1 
│ │ │ ├─┬ minimatch@2.0.10 
│ │ │ │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.3 
│ │ │ │   ├── balanced-match@0.3.0 
│ │ │ │   └── concat-map@0.0.1 
│ │ │ └── once@1.3.3 
│ │ ├── lodash@2.4.2 
│ │ ├── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │ ├── propprop@0.3.0 
│ │ └─┬ through2@0.6.5 
│ │   ├─┬ readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ │   │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.2 
│ │   │ ├── isarray@0.0.1 
│ │   │ └── string_decoder@0.10.31 
│ │   └── xtend@4.0.1 
│ ├─┬ yeoman-generator@0.16.0 
│ │ ├── async@0.2.10 
│ │ ├─┬ chalk@0.4.0 
│ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@1.0.0 
│ │ │ ├── has-color@0.1.7 
│ │ │ └── strip-ansi@0.1.1 
│ │ ├─┬ cheerio@0.13.1 
│ │ │ ├─┬ CSSselect@0.4.1 
│ │ │ │ ├── CSSwhat@0.4.7 
│ │ │ │ └── domutils@1.4.3 
│ │ │ ├── entities@0.5.0 
│ │ │ ├─┬ htmlparser2@3.4.0 
│ │ │ │ ├── domelementtype@1.3.0 
│ │ │ │ ├── domhandler@2.2.1 
│ │ │ │ ├── domutils@1.3.0 
│ │ │ │ └── readable-stream@1.1.13 
│ │ │ └── underscore@1.5.2 
│ │ ├─┬ class-extend@0.1.2 
│ │ │ └── object-assign@2.1.1 
│ │ ├── dargs@0.1.0 
│ │ ├── debug@0.7.4 
│ │ ├── diff@1.0.8 
│ │ ├─┬ download@0.1.19 
│ │ │ ├─┬ decompress@0.2.5 
│ │ │ │ ├── adm-zip@0.4.7 
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ ext-name@1.0.1 
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ ext-list@0.2.0 
│ │ │ │ │   └─┬ got@0.2.0 
│ │ │ │ │     └── object-assign@0.3.1 
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ stream-combiner@0.0.4 
│ │ │ │ │ └── duplexer@0.1.1 
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ tar@0.1.20 
│ │ │ │ │ ├── block-stream@0.0.8 
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ fstream@0.1.31 
│ │ │ │ │   ├── graceful-fs@3.0.8 
│ │ │ │ │   └─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1 
│ │ │ │ │     └── minimist@0.0.8 
│ │ │ │ └─┬ tempfile@0.1.3 
│ │ │ │   └── uuid@1.4.2 
│ │ │ ├── each-async@0.1.3 
│ │ │ ├── get-stdin@0.1.0 
│ │ │ ├── get-urls@0.1.2 
│ │ │ ├─┬ nopt@2.2.1 
│ │ │ │ └── abbrev@1.0.7 
│ │ │ ├─┬ request@2.69.0 
│ │ │ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.6.0 
│ │ │ │ ├── aws4@1.2.1 
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ bl@1.0.3 
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@2.0.5 
│ │ │ │ │   ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.6 
│ │ │ │ │   └── util-deprecate@1.0.2 
│ │ │ │ ├── caseless@0.11.0 
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ combined-stream@1.0.5 
│ │ │ │ │ └── delayed-stream@1.0.0 
│ │ │ │ ├── extend@3.0.0 
│ │ │ │ ├── forever-agent@0.6.1 
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ form-data@1.0.0-rc3 
│ │ │ │ │ └── async@1.5.2 
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ har-validator@2.0.6 
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ commander@2.9.0 
│ │ │ │ │ │ └── graceful-readlink@1.0.1 
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ is-my-json-valid@2.12.4 
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├── generate-function@2.0.0 
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ generate-object-property@1.2.0 
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── is-property@1.0.2 
│ │ │ │ │ │ └── jsonpointer@2.0.0 
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ pinkie-promise@2.0.0 
npm WARN generator-angular@0.15.1 requires a peer of generator-karma@>=0.9.0 but none was installed.

│ │ │ │ ├─┬ hawk@3.1.3 
│ │ │ │ │ ├── boom@2.10.1 
│ │ │ │ │ ├── cryptiles@2.0.5 
│ │ │ │ │ ├── hoek@2.16.3 
│ │ │ │ │ └── sntp@1.0.9 
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ http-signature@1.1.1 
│ │ │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.2.0 
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ jsprim@1.2.2 
│   │ │ │ │ │ ├── extsprintf@1.0.2 
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├── json-schema@0.2.2 
│ │ │ │ │ │ └── verror@1.3.6 
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ sshpk@1.7.4 
│ │ │ │ │   ├── asn1@0.2.3 
│ │ │ │ │   ├─┬ dashdash@1.13.0 
│ │ │ │ │   │ └── assert-plus@1.0.0 
│ │ │ │ │   ├── ecc-jsbn@0.1.1 
│ │ │ │ │   ├── jodid25519@1.0.2 
│ │ │ │ │   ├── jsbn@0.1.0 
│ │ │ │ │   └── tweetnacl@0.13.3 
│ │ │ │ ├── is-typedarray@1.0.0 
│ │ │ │ ├── isstream@0.1.2 
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.9 
│ │ │ │ │ └── mime-db@1.21.0 
│ │ │ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.8.1 
│ │ │ │ ├── qs@6.0.2 
│ │ │ │ ├── stringstream@0.0.5 
│ │ │ │ ├── tough-cookie@2.2.1 
│ │ │ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.4.2 
│ │ │ └─┬ through2@0.4.2 
│ │ │   └─┬ xtend@2.1.2 
│ │ │     └── object-keys@0.4.0 
│ │ ├─┬ file-utils@0.1.5 
│ │ │ ├─┬ glob@3.2.11 
│ │ │ │ └── minimatch@0.3.0 
│ │ │ ├── isbinaryfile@0.1.9 
│ │ │ ├── lodash@2.1.0 
│ │ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.2.14 
│ │ │   ├── lru-cache@2.7.3 
│ │ │   └── sigmund@1.0.1 
│ │ ├─┬ findup-sync@0.1.3 
│ │ │ └─┬ glob@3.2.11 
│ │ │   └── minimatch@0.3.0 
│ │ ├─┬ glob@3.2.11 
│ │ │ └── minimatch@0.3.0 
│ │ ├── iconv-lite@0.2.11 
│ │ ├─┬ inquirer@0.4.1 
│ │ │ ├─┬ cli-color@0.2.3 
│ │ │ │ ├── es5-ext@0.9.2 
│ │ │ │ └─┬ memoizee@0.2.6 
│ │ │ │   ├── event-emitter@0.2.2 
│ │ │ │   └── next-tick@0.1.0 
│ │ │ ├── mute-stream@0.0.4 
│ │ │ ├─┬ readline2@0.1.1 
│ │ │ │ └─┬ strip-ansi@2.0.1 
│ │ │ │   └── ansi-regex@1.1.1 
│ │ │ └── through@2.3.8 
│ │ ├── isbinaryfile@2.0.4 
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.11 
│ │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5 
│ │ ├─┬ request@2.30.0 
│ │ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.5.0 
│ │ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2 
│ │ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.4 
│ │ │ │ ├── async@0.9.2 
│ │ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.7 
│ │ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5 
│ │ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0 
│ │ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2 
│ │ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2 
│ │ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1 
│ │ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4 
│ │ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.1 
│ │ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11 
│ │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.5 
│ │ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.3 
│ │ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 
│ │ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.7 
│ │ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0 
│ │ │ ├── qs@0.6.6 
│ │ │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@0.9.15 
│ │ │ │ └── punycode@1.4.0 
│ │ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0 
│ │ ├── rimraf@2.2.8 
│ │ ├── shelljs@0.2.6 
│ │ ├── text-table@0.2.0 
│ │ └── underscore.string@2.3.3 
│ └─┬ yosay@1.1.0 
│   ├── ansi-regex@2.0.0 
│   ├── pad-component@0.0.1 
│   ├─┬ repeating@2.0.0 
│   │ └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1 
│   │   └── number-is-nan@1.0.0 
│   ├─┬ string-width@1.0.1 
│   │ ├── code-point-at@1.0.0 
│   │ └── is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0 
│   ├─┬ taketalk@1.0.0 
│   │ └── get-stdin@4.0.1 
│   └── word-wrap@1.1.0 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY generator-karma@>=0.9.0
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Answer (score 9):

You must install all the components on one line, as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867574/npm-install-g-generator-angular-gives-error-requires-a-peer-of).

```
npm install -g grunt-cli bower yo generator-karma generator-angular
```